# combining all possible results in one list in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm trying to find the available slot which comes from the predicate quizslots/3 quizslot(Group, Day, Slot).

> quizslot(group4, tuesday, 1).
>
> quizslot(group4, thursday, 1).
>
> quizslot(group6, saturday, 5).

This is my hypothesis but it doesn't seem to work fine.

> available_timings(G,L):-
>       setof(X,quizslot(G,X,_),L).

I want the result for (group4,L), L = [tuesday,1,thursday,1].

Comment: You're wanting the slot as part of your answer, but you're telling `setof/3` to ignore the slot. Also, is the form `[tuesday, 1, thursday, 1]` required? It seems a little odd to alternate day and slot number at the same level in the list. If you do `setof([Day,Slot], quizslot(G, Day, Slot), L)` you'll get `[[tuesday, 1], [thursday,1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of [setof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3):

```
% Set of every FooResult
?- setof(FooResult,foo(X,Y,FooResult),Result).
   [FooResult1, FooResult2, ..]

% Set of tuples of every input X and FooResult
?- setof((X,FooResult),foo(X,Y,FooResult),Result).
   [(X1,FooResult1), (X2,FooResult2), ..]

% Set of lists of every input X and FooResult, ommitting input Y
?- setof([X,FooResult],foo(X,_,FooResult),Result).
   [[X1,FooResult1], [X2,FooResult2], ..]
```

I think you get the point. As lurker stated in his answer above, you are trying to have the slot included in the result, however, you tell prolog to find all distinct quizslot-facts of the form:

```
quizslot(group G, day X, whatever slot)
```

Since this wildcard will match with any slot, you cannot retrieve the actual variable holding the slot, Prolog didn't bother retrieving the variable for you.

A correct usage would be, for example, one of the following

```
setof([Day,Slot], quizslot(Group,Day,Slot), Result)    % List of lists
setof((Day,Slot), quizslot(Group,Day,Slot), Result)    % List of tuples
```

Comment: Or, `setof(Day-Slot, quizslot(Group,Day,Slot), Result)` or `setof(day_slot(Day, Slot), quizslot(Group,Day,Slot), Result)`, etc.